# is there a difference between MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1) and MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)?

Tags: django, django-models, model

Is there a difference in the result between:

```
 MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1)
```

and

```
 MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
```

If there is no difference, then why does the .get() method exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.get() always returns that object if it exists (and if there is exactly one). It also raises an exception if it does not exist.  For example

```
blah =  MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
```

blah is an instance of MyModel.  .filter() on the other hand does not return an error if it does not exist.

```
blah =  MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1234234234)
```

Then blah is a an empty query. You can check this by calling .count() on blah. if blah.count() == 0 means that there is no MyModel items with the key 1234234234.  Likewise, if there are many items with that query say:

```
blah =  MyModel.objects.filter(name__contains="Brian")
```

The you get a query result that can be interated over to get each result:

```
  for b in blah:
      print b.name
```

Also, another interesting method simular to .get() is .get_or_create() http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/get_or_create/ With this you can say:

```
blah,created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(name="Brian Ray", 
                                             cool=False, 
                                             fun=True)
```

If there already is a BrianRay that would normally been returned with the .get() it just returns that instance; otherwise, it creates it. Notice it returns two things. The second is just a flag to let the caller know what actually happened.

HTH, Brian Ray

Answer (score 4):

Filter returns a list of MyModels (in this case a list of one). Get returns one instance of MyModel.

By the way: you can test these things by running:

```
manage.py shell
from myapp import models

models.MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1)

models.MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
```

Look at the output of that.

Comment: Also note that `get` throws a `DoesNotExist` exception when the object is not found and throws a `MultipleObjectsFound` exception when there are more than one.  `filter` on the other hand returns an empty list in the former case and obviously handles the latter case.